# How to update a nested bigquery column with data from another bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 `bigquery` tables with nested columns, I need to update all the columns in `table1` whenever  `table1.value1=table2.value`,  also those tables having a huge amount of data.

I could update a single nested column with static column like below,

```sql
    #standardSQL
    UPDATE `ck.table1` 
    SET promotion_id = ARRAY(
      SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE (100 AS PromotionId ) FROM UNNEST(promotion_id)
    )
```

But when I try to reuse the same to update multiple columns based on table2 data I am getting exceptions.

I am trying to update `table1` with `table2` data whenever the `table1.value1=table2.value` with all the nested columns.

As of now, both tables are having a similar schema.

Comment: please provide to us the exception you are receiving

Answer (score 1):

> I need to update **all** the columns in table1 whenever table1.value1=table2.value
>   ... both tables are having a **similar** schema

I assume by `similar` you meant `same`

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL
You can use below query to get combining result and save it back to table1 either using `destination table` or `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE` syntax

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE IF(value IS NULL, t1, t2)
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
ON value1 = value
```

I have not tried this approach with `UPDATE` syntax  - but you can try and let us know :o)